# Is there a way to run a file by its association while directing its stdout?

Tags: c#, windows

I can do:

```
using (var process = new Process()) {
    process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    //process.StartInfo.Verb = "Open";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    ...

}
```

But then I have to look for its association ([`AssocQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringa)), parse the association string, which can be quite complicated, like:

```
"%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"
```

Or:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Then split to executable part, expand it using `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(exeFile)`, then replace all percentages with parsed argmunets, and so on.

In few cases the association string can be very odd, such as (note all the slashes - who knows if it even works...):

```
\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client\R_SERVER\\\bin\\x64\\RGui.exe\" \"%1\"
```

I can use the obsolete [`WinExec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec) or [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea), but then I can't redirect stdout/stderr.

Calling [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) works basically like C#'s `new Process()`: MSDN states that

> ... Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key.

So am I doomed to do all the work on my own? no easier solution?

Comment: Why arent you just passing the string you have to the cmd.exe and let it run the command?

Comment: I really can't think of an app that I have that's associated with a file type that reads from or writes to StdIn or StdOut (so I can't test this).  However, if I use `UseShellExecute=true` in a `ProcessStartInfo` and the name of a file with a particular file type, I'm able to fire up an app by just knowing a file name (`FileName = stuff.jpg` in the `ProcessStartInfo`).  Does `UseShellExecute = true` preclude redirection?

Comment: @Hozikimaru, CMD implements this by changing its own standard handles before calling `ShellExecuteEx`. This works if the target executable is a console application. A non-console (GUI) app does not implicitly inherit the parent's standard handles. That said, non-console applications rarely have use for standard I/O, and the shell actually repurposes the standard-handle values to set a hotkey and pass a preferred monitor handle.

Comment: @Hozikimaru, I tried with `StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"` and `StartInfo.Arguments = "script.py"`, while `script.py` contains merely `print 'hi'`. But all I get in stdout is: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.665]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

Comment: @Flydog57 - sadly no, it seems to be mutually exclusive: if I set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, I get an `InvalidOperationException`: `'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.'`

Comment: @eryksun, what are you saying? if it is a console app there is something I can do?

Comment: Wow, what an informative exception!  Those are pretty rare.

Comment: Console applications implicitly inherit the standard handles of the parent process. Actually they get duplicated to the child, so they're not necessarily the same handle *value*, but that doesn't matter for standard I/O. Just set your process standard handles via `SetStdHandle` before creating the child process. Obviously save the current handles via `GetStdHandle` if restoring them matters, and use a lock to serialize the procedure if multithreaded concurrency is an issue.

Comment: Apparently you'd have to P/Invoke `ShellExecuteExW` since the .NET Process class doesn't provide a way to pass the flag `SEE_MASK_NO_CONSOLE`. Without this flag, the `ShellExecuteExW` call implicitly uses the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flag of `CreateProcess`, which always overrides the parent's standard handles with handles for the new console's input and output buffers. You could also use CMD to open the file, as suggested above, which will take care of all of this for you. CMD would have to be run with `UseShellExecute` as `false`, so you can control its inherited standard handles.

Comment: As a note, you get this: `"%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"` when you use the `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` enum. You could use `ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE`, which returns the *clean* executable path (not a viable solution in some cases, though). The environment variables should be already expanded in this format. You could also run `cmd.exe start /WAIT`. If the program writes to stdout, you should get it.